# Unable to run a google script in a document owned by a Google Service Account

Tags: google-apps-script, service-accounts, google-account, google-drive-shared-drive

I contact you because I face an issue on a project regarding the execution of an embedded script in a google document:

We have implemented a solution that copy google sheet templates from google drive to a shared drive with a google service account.

When the user tries to execute the document (App Script inside google sheet)'s script in the shared drive, an error message indicates only the owner can perform this action, which is impossible since by default the owner of the document is so the google service account.
Is there a solution to solve this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: How user execute the script?

Comment: did you check if the account type for the users are all business account type?  Non-business account user is not able to create document inside the Shared Drive.

Comment: You contact us? Please read on [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @vector user run Extensions - Apps Script - run the .gs embedded in Google sheet

Comment: @liquidkat yes users are all business account type and they can create document inside the Shared Drive

Comment: Are you able to share a sample of code and the console log message?